# Multiple Transforms for an single object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Is there any possibility to use multiple transforms for an single object (i.e how to use `ScaleTranform`, `CompositeTransform`, and `TranslateTransform` on a single `Ellipse`). I tried using two transforms as below.

```
<Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform  x:Name="CoinTransform" Y="0.36" />
    <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleCoin" ScaleX="0.336"/>
</Ellipse.RenderTransform>
```

...but it shows error message as `RenderTransform` is set more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd put the distinct transforms inside of a [TransformGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transformgroup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

So your code would look like this:

```
<Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <TranslateTransform  x:Name="CoinTransform" Y="0.36" />
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleCoin" ScaleX="0.336"/>
    </TransformGroup>
</Ellipse.RenderTransform>
```